# Access another program config file

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I have program A windows application and program B another windows application.
In program B I need to show program A config file. (App.config)
That should show in a text box in program B.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path of config file of program A);
```

you can try this one